# add appcompat-v7 dependency and not using appcompat as parent theme error

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat

i need the Holo themes, but the appcompat functionality however Gradle is complaining that appcompat has no defined parent style. so what's the workaround here? thanks.

Comment: Use AppCompat, not Holo. Holo is old. Use Android Studio and Gradle.

Comment: only reason i stopped using appcompat was because it was tricky to use for styling the actionBar and i got fed up.. oh well back to square one i suppose

Comment: No. The `Toolbar` comes with `AppCompat` which makes it very easy to style.

Comment: Could you include the style code that gradle is complaining about?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an `AppCompatActivity` you **have to** use an AppCompat Theme.

If you want to use Holo, you can't use `AppCompatActivity` (for example you can use a simple Activity).

Pay attention: today is very difficult to work without the AppCompat Library. For example the new Design Support Library requires AppCompat.